# How can I set secret environment variables in launch.json of VSCode for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode debugger and and setting environment variables via the `env` property. I also have database password and secrets that I need to set as env vars but I'd like to check in `launch.json` so the debugging settings can be shared amongst the team etc.

Is there a way I can set these sensitive environment variables for debugging without actually checking it into source control?

Comment: It's crazy there isn't a better solution for this (assuming you can't just interpolate an environment variable because it might not be set when VS Code was started -- for remote editing, I'm not even sure how I could set it).  Interpolating the output of a command would seem to be an obvious way, but it is not straightforward to use a normal program as a command, though an answer to this question suggests an extension that can do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747689/using-a-shell-command-as-vscode-task-variable-value

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple of ways to reference sensitive data from Visual Studio Code (vscode) inside launch.json without including the data in the launch.json file.

- Environment Variables
- Input Variables : Prompt
- Input Variables : Custom Command

The vscode [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) documents these solutions nicely.

## Environment Variables ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables))

You can put your sensitive variables in an environment variable (perhaps loaded via your shell profile such as in `.bash_profile` for example).  You can then reference it "through the `${env:Name}` syntax (for example, `${env:USERNAME}`)."

```json
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "args": ["${env:USERNAME}"]
}
```

## Input Variables ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables))

### Prompt for Input

You can prompt for sensitive information on launch by defining a `promptString` input type as seen in the below configuration extracted from the docs.  Below `${input:componentName}` is used as an argument and defined below in an `inputs` section as a `promptString` for prompting you for the value when you run the associated task.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "ng g",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "ng",
      "args": ["g", "${input:componentType}", "${input:componentName}"]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    /** skipping componentType definition for brevity -- see docs for that */
    {
      "type": "promptString",
      "id": "componentName",
      "description": "Name your component.",
      "default": "my-new-component"
    }
  ]
}
```

The definition of a `promptString` is as follows:

> - **description**: Shown in the quick input, provides context for the input.
> - **default**: Default value that will be used if the user doesn't enter something else.
> - **password**: Set to true to input with a password prompt that will not show the typed value.

### Run a Custom Command for the Input

You can also run a custom command for getting the input.  The docs use the following configuration as an example.  Note that like other input types that the command must be defined in the `inputs` section with a `type`.

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run specific test",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${input:pickTest}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickTest",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.mochaSupport.testPicker",
      "args": {
        "testFolder": "/out/tests"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The other options for the `command` type are:

> - **command**: Command being run on variable interpolation.
> - **args**: Optional option bag passed to the command's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a workaround for this which is to use the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

Thus instead of relying on VSCode to load the environment variables, they're being loaded from within the application itself.